# KeyBoard Stroke Events

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events, keystroke

what i want to do is have a background application which by itself or its modules run only when a certain key is pressed. Like when i press F10 some code that i have written executes and then quits or goes to sleep then again when i press F10 i executes again and goes to sleep but in between keystrokes it does not takes any processor time. How can i do it

For example a thread that executes its statements and then

```
thread.Sleep( "till i press F10" );
```

well this is an imaginary function. Any help from the real world :)

C# + Winforms

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `WH_KEYBOARD` or `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook type.  Calling it from C# may be a bit obnoxious, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try console.ReadKey which will read the key and immediately perform some operation n as soon as task gets finished u call thread.Sleep()